# I cannot load the help.chm file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to show a help file (help.chm) when pressing F1 button.
The problem is whenever I use this code, everything seems to be working

```
HelpProvider.HelpNamespace = "C:\Help.chm"
```

However, when I am trying to use the file that is in my application directory, it will not work

```
HelpProvider.HelpNamespace = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Help.chm"
```

I am not getting any errors while building the application nor when I press F1. BTW this is the rest of my code for HelpProvider

```
HelpProvider.SetHelpKeyword(Me, Nothing)
HelpProvider.SetHelpNavigator(Me, HelpNavigator.TableOfContents)
HelpProvider.SetShowHelp(Me, True)
```

Comment: Never used VB, thats why I can't say if your backslash would need some escaping. But try it with [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is made for this.

Comment: The code shown is fine. If you do a `MessageBox.Show(HelpProvider.HelpNamespace)` right after the assignment, what does it show? And is the help file actually in that location?

Comment: My crystal ball says that the file is stored in your project directory, not the application directory (bin\Debug).

Comment: msgbox showed the path to Help.chm file, which is in bin\Debug\Help.chm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
HelpProvider.HelpNamespace = Application.StartupPath & "\Help.chm"
```